# Get key for a specific function in Function APP in ARM template

Tags: azure-functions, azure-resource-manager

I want to get a key for one specific function inside my Function App inside my ARM template.

When I use this line:

```
"outputs": {
    "function_key": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[listsecrets(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/functions', parameters('functionAppName'), variables('theFunction_Name')),'2020-06-01').key]"
    }
}
```

or:

```
 "outputs": {
    "function_key": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[listsecrets(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/functions', parameters('functionAppName'), variables('theFunction_Name')),'2020-06-01').default]"
    }
}
```

I got this error:

```
Status Message: System.InvalidOperationException: Runtime keys are stored on blob storage. This API doesn't support this configuration. Please change Environment
variable AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType value to 'Files'. For more info, visit https://aka.ms/funcsecrets
at Kudu.Core.Functions.FunctionManager.<GetKeyObjectFromFile>d__9`1.MoveNext() in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Functions\FunctionManager.cs:line 141
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Kudu.Core.Functions.FunctionManager.<GetFunctionSecretsAsync>d__12.MoveNext() in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Core\Functions\FunctionManager.cs:line 220
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Kudu.Services.Functions.FunctionController.<GetSecrets>d__12.MoveNext() in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Services\Functions\FunctionController.cs:line 141
(Code:Conflict)
CorrelationId: ddd493fd-2386-45a3-999f-88b1d7a44514
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzResourceGroupDeployment  -ResourceGroupName INT014Test -Templat ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

I see many people trying to use the host key of the function App instead of using the specific key of the function needed, They use something like:

```
"value": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/host', parameters('functionAppName'),'default'),'2018-02-01').functionKeys.default]"
```

1. I don't understand why to use the host key instead of the function key, is it safer or just an easier solution?
2. If I still want to use the function key instead of host key, how can I got it?

Answer (score 0):

We can implement the output as below for the function app.
Way 1:

```
{
  "variables": {
    "functionApp": {
      "name": "my-function-app",
      "functionName": "my-function"
    },
    "resourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/functions', variables('functionApp').name, variables('functionApp').functionName)]",
    "apiVersion": "[providers('Microsoft.Web', 'sites').apiVersions[0]]"
  },
  "resources": [],
  "outputs": {
    "functionKey": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[listSecrets(variables('resourceId'), variables('apiVersion')).key]"
    }
  }
}
```

Way 2:

```
"outputs": {
"FunctionAppName": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "[parameters('functionName')]"
},
"Key": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "[listsecrets(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/functions', parameters('existingFunctionAppName'), parameters('functionName')),'2015-08-01').key]"
},        
"Url": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "[listsecrets(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/functions', parameters('existingFunctionAppName'), parameters('functionName')),'2015-08-01').trigger_url]"
}        
}
```

For more information refer to the [documentation](https://devkimchi.com/2018/01/05/list-of-access-keys-from-output-values-after-arm-template-deployment/)

Below is the information form the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/security-concepts#keys-comparison) where we can know the correct valid keys to check based on our requirement whether it is specific function or any function.

[image]

Comment: One thing to keep in mind when outputting a secret, is that that secret now becomes visible to users with ReadOnly permissions.  A better practice is to output the resourceId and consume the secret (i.e. listsecret() function) where it's needed.

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned, I got an error when I use the solution you mentioned. I had already written the error details in the question

Comment: @bmoore-msft thanks for your advice. However, I put it in the output just to make sure that it is working and to make the question shorter

Comment: @ibda Try adding ("AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "Files") along with AzureWebJobsStorage in your JSON settings file, match this in your application settings

Comment: @ibda - thanks, good to clarify for others that may stumble across this in the future...